# Turn off collection but keep its lighting?

Tags: compositing-nodes, lighting, viewlayers

I have a scene with two vehicles scaled as models on the desk of an office with a window and lamps casting light, as well as ambient lighting. We see this at the start of my video. However, at the end of my video, I want to show only the two vehicles (plus shadow catcher for placement on a white background) so that people think they're full size vehicles, but then I want to pull the camera back and cross-fade into a render with the whole office so we can now see that they're the two desk models we saw at the beginning of the video. Cool effect... but how can I maintain the office environment's lighting on the vehicles when the office is invisible? Is there a way with view layers and compositing?  Blender 3.4.1

[image]

Comment: Looks like I'm homing in on an answer using render layers, alpha channels and a shadow catcher pass for the compositor. I don't know for sure that it'll get me to where I need to be, but it's looking hopeful. :)